My app shows google login panel, I changed the email and client Id in the code then get this error
I'm using for google sso

react-native-google-signin/google-signin

Error is:

{"nativeStackAndroid":[],"userInfo":null,"message":"A non-recoverable
sign in failure occurred","code":"12500"}

code was working fine before change client ID:
`
const googleSignIN = () => {
GoogleSignin.configure({
androidClientId: CLIENT_ID
})

    GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices().then((hasPlayService) => {
        if (hasPlayService) {
            GoogleSignin.signIn().then(async (userInfo) => {
                console.log("userInfo", JSON.stringify(userInfo.user))
                setLoading(true);
                const social_Login_Data = {
                    email: userInfo.user.email,
                    name: userInfo.user.name
                }
                console.log("social_Login_Data : ", social_Login_Data);
                try {
                    const res = await api.post(`/Auth/login-single-signin`, social_Login_Data);
                    console.log("response : ", res.data);
                    if (res.data.ack === 1) {
                        console.log('success');
                        navigation.navigate('DrawerNavigation')
                    } else {
                        setItem('social_Login_Data', JSON.stringify(social_Login_Data))
                        navigation.navigate('VerifyEmail',{msg:res.data.message})
                    }
                    setLoading(false);
                } catch (e) {
                    setLoading(false);
                    alert(e)
                }
            }).catch((e) => {
                setLoading(false);
                console.log("ERROR IS1: " + JSON.stringify(e));
            })
        }
    }).catch((e) => {
        console.log("ERROR IS2: " + JSON.stringify(e));
    })
}`

Please help if anyone got this error and solved this.

Follow these steps :

cd ./android && ./gradlew signingReport
Take the SHA1 of Task :app:signingReport, Variant: debugAndroidTest, Config: debug
Update it in the Firebase Console under Project Settings, Android app, add the SHA1
Download the google-services.json, put it in ./android/app
Go to Authentication, then Sign-in method, then press Google



Take the Web client ID and use that for your GoogleSignin.configure({ webClientId: ... });
This Web client ID should be the same as listed in https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=<your_project_id> -> Credentials -> OAuth 2 Client ID -> Web Client


Add support Email > Select Your project and open settings tab.


Reference link

https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E6Rdg0reKRI



I'm not using firebase. I have directly implement google cloud.
I followed this tutorial : https://ibjects.medium.com/google-signin-tutorial-for-react-native-81a57fb67b18

Have you added correct package name and SHA1 of release.keystore certificate ? Also make sure not to use same google account for signing which is used for setup.

I resolved this issue myself. It was my mistake: I had registered the same package name with two different Google accounts, which caused the error.
Thanks @Bob
